# Programming a game of guessing number - I can't get while loop to work (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

I'm programming a game where a random number from 1-20 is generated, the user guesses the number. If he guesses wrong, his score is deducted by 1 everytime (score starts at 20). When score reaches 0, the game is over.

My difficulty is getting the game to keep going while score is above 0 and stop when it's 0.

At first, I put in the while loop within the click event:

```
//to generate a random number
const random_number = Math.trunc(Math.random() * 20) + 1;
//display random (only for testing purpose, not in the actual game)
document.querySelector('.number').textContent = random_number;
//every player starts with 20. Everytime they guess wrong it gets deducted by 1
let score = 20;
//player input their number. Check for player input against random number generated above

document.querySelector('.check').addEventListener('click', function () {
  //I put while loop here so that when score is 0 it is game over but game continues as long as score>0
  while (score > 0) {
    //take the player's guess
    const guess = Number(document.querySelector('.guess').value);
    if (!guess) {
      //if it's blank
      document.querySelector('.message').textContent = 'No number';
      //if guess is correct, break out of the loop.
    } else if (guess === random_number) {
      document.querySelector('.message').textContent = 'correct number';
      break;
    } else {
      score--; //score gets deducted by one
      document.querySelector('.score').textContent = score; //the score displayed on the html is set to score in script
      if (guess > random_number) {
        document.querySelector('.message').textContent = 'too high';
      } else if (guess < random_number) {
        document.querySelector('.message').textContent = 'too low';
      }
      break; //once it's deducted, should break out of while loop
    }
  }
  if ((score = 0)) {
    document.querySelector('.message').textContent = 'game over';
  }
});
```

It only works once, so if I click "check" again, the game does doesn't continue.

So I tried to put while loop outside of the event:

```
const random_number = Math.trunc(Math.random() * 20) + 1;
//display random (only for testing purpose, not in the actual game)
document.querySelector('.number').textContent = random_number;
//every player starts with 20. Everytime they guess wrong it gets deducted by 1
let score = 20;

//putting while loop outside of event this time
while (score > 0) {
  document.querySelector('.check').addEventListener('click', function () {
    //take the player's guess
    const guess = Number(document.querySelector('.guess').value);
    if (!guess) {
      //if it's blank
      document.querySelector('.message').textContent = 'No number';
      //if guess is correct, break out of the loop. Script works well up to here
    } else if (guess === random_number) {
      document.querySelector('.message').textContent = 'correct number';
      //I want to put a break here but it says illegal break
    } else {
      score--; //score gets deducted by one
      document.querySelector('.score').textContent = score; //the score displayed on the html is set to score in script
      if (guess > random_number) {
        document.querySelector('.message').textContent = 'too high';
      } else if (guess < random_number) {
        document.querySelector('.message').textContent = 'too low';
      }
      //I want to put a break here but it says illegal break
    }
  });
  break;
}

if ((score = 0)) {
  document.querySelector('.message').textContent = 'game over';
}
```

This time I can play the game multiple times, but I cannot stop the while loop from running if a guess is wrong so the score ends up getting to -1 on the very first wrong guess. I try to put the break statements like before but it keeps saying 'illegal breaks'. Not sure where I'm supposed to put the breaks?

Comment: It might be this line here: `if ((score = 0)){...` that is setting the value of score to 0 rather than checking if it is. Use `==` to compare -- `if ((score == 0)){...`

Comment: You are using `EventListener` for the wrong purpose. Basically, an `event listener` is similar to `while` loop, you could not nest them together.

Answer (score 1):

No need for a while loop. Evaluate if the `score` is `0` at in the `else` block inside your event listener. You only want to evaluate the `score` again whenever you subtract from it.

At the start, evaluate if the `.guess` field's value is empty. Doing `Number('')` will produce `0`. That means that even if I would enter the number `0`, I would get the message `No number`.

```
document.querySelector('.check').addEventListener('click', function() {
  const value = document.querySelector('.guess').value;
  const guess = Number(value);

  if (value === '') {
    document.querySelector('.message').textContent = 'No number';
  } else if (guess === random_number) {
    document.querySelector('.message').textContent = 'correct number';
  } else {
    score--; //score gets deducted by one
    document.querySelector('.score').textContent = score;

    if (score === 0) {
      document.querySelector('.message').textContent = 'game over';
    } else if (guess > random_number) {
      document.querySelector('.message').textContent = 'too high';
    } else if (guess < random_number) {
      document.querySelector('.message').textContent = 'too low';
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: damn thank you. I feel so dumb now. Another question. There's a button called "again" so if someone clicks on it it will reset the game (basically the score value, random number etc..)
Is there a quick way to do it without adding another event listener then resetting every values manually?

Comment: No need to feel that way. You asked for help and you're learning. Kudos to you. And to answer your question, the way you describe it is actually exactly the way you should implement it. New event listener that sets `score` back to `20`, etc. Another tip, store references to your elements in a variable in the top scope, e.g. `const message = document.querySelector('.message');`. The element won't go anywhere, so this way you don't have to "look it up" more than once.

Comment: So there's no quick way to do it? I'd also have to reset the messages as well. And I didn't you could do that! Always thought you have to do document.queryselector every time according to the course I'm following...

Comment: Unfortunately no. The logic you're proposing seems quite specific and custom, so you'll have to create that. And for the storing in variables: as long as you can safely assume that the element will be there, then you could store it in a variable. If a list of elements changes dynamically and you need the most up-to-date snapshot of that list, then you'll need to query every time.

Comment: thanks. So I add an event lister for the button again as follows:

document.querySelector('.again').addEventListener('click', function () {
  let score = 20;
  let random_number = Math.trunc(Math.random() * 20) + 1;
  number.textContent = random_number;

  message.textContent = 'Start guessing...';
  document.querySelector('.score').textContent = score;

It all looks fine at first, as when I click again there is a new random number generated at the top and I can see it. However, when I tried to guess that number (click guess), it says I'm wrong. The random number is different :(

Comment: So apparently, the random number was reset more than once after I click again, and I have no idea why

Comment: It's because you create **new** `score` and `random_number` variables. But you need to reference the ones that already exist, like you do in your other event listener. Using `let` and `const` allows you to create variables with existing names, as long as they are in a different scope than the existing variables. Remove `let` from the code in your event listener.